# Increase System Tray Icon Size in KDE

Tags: kde, kubuntu, icons, plasma5, tray

How can I increase the size of these System Tray Icons? :

[image]

**Update:** In Debian 11, KDE Plasma 5.20.5, there is now an option to scale system-tray icons to the panel's height. Here's is a [short video](https://youtu.be/S7vrbWFWaqg) showing that. Thanks goes to KDE!

Comment: @DKBose : plasmashell 5.16.5

Comment: @DKBose : Well, I'm not sure this will help, but I remember having to insert the `iconSize=3` line about 3 times (maybe its because I have 3 monitors and each one has a system tray on a tool bar), but each time I added a new line directly under the line that started `extraItem=. . .` and then put `iconSize=3` onto that new line. After saving those changes to the file, and rebooting, the system tray icons where way bigger (like I like them).

Comment: @DKBose If you discover what works in 20.04 be sure to post back here. I intend to upgrade to that in April and I'm enjoying this hack in 19.10.

Comment: Update: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/fjf6jv/. The responder there is a KDE dev. In any case, I'd suggest waiting for 20.04.1 sometime around October 2020, testing in a VM or via a USB stick, and then doing a clean install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open **~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc** with a text editor.

Find every line starting with **extraItems=**

Add another line **iconSize=3** below each of those.

Save the edited file and exit.

After a reboot the icons should have a much higher limit of size when adjusting the height of the panel.

Comment: Oooh, that's fantastic. It should do that by default. At the very least, you should be able to right-click on the system-tray and configure this setting instead of having to modify some text files. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, Plasma Systemtray version 1.0, shell version 5.20.2

Comment: @xryl669 - From 5.19 you have to look for other tricks, like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644751/341192). And isn't there a new setting under "Configure System Tray" that lets icons resize with the panel? (I'm in 5.18 now)

Comment: Thanks again for showing me this solution; it got me through Kubuntu 20.04. Today I noticed that KDE Plasma (5.20.5) [now provides this as an option in the GUI](https://youtu.be/S7vrbWFWaqg). It comes default in Debian 11.

Comment: You do not have to reboot, it's possible just to reload Plasma and surprisingly it works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out

Comment: If this advice is not working for you, make sure you have set the panel to be at least 45px tall.

Answer (score 4):

## Debian 11, KDE Plasma

In order to increase the size of systray icons, you need to edit the file

```
/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/ui/main.qml
```

1. Find the string `readonly property int smallIconSize: units.iconSzie.smallMedium`
2. Replace `smallMedium` (22 log. px) with `medium` (32 log. px), `large`, or use integer value (in physical pixels!)
3. Save, log out, log in, or restart Plasma with

   ```
   killall plasmashell ; kstart plasmashell
   ```

This file will get overwritten every time there's a Plasma update.
To edit settings for a specific user only and avoid problem with plasma update, copy the entire plasmoid (systemtray):

```
cp -r /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/
```

and then edit main.qml and restart plasmashell.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this has changed as of Plasma version 5.21.4 (perhaps slightly earlier). The `iconSize` setting now does nothing.

To get this functionality, instead, at the same place where you would have inserted `iconSize` (per the other answers), put: `scaleIconsToFit=true`

Then simply `killall plasmashell; plasmashell &` as described and it will work perfectly.

Comment: what works in newer Plasma is the new setting under "Configure System Tray" that lets icons resize with the pnel

Comment: @cipricus I think I recall that being there too, but IIRC it was for fixed sizes and for me all of them were too small or too big.

Comment: the version changes involved came (as many others) with 5.19.x. Now I'm back to 5.18 (kubuntu 20 LTS, so [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568798/341192) works for me), but it's always good to have a solution for the future :)

Comment: @cipricus ok. This works in the newer plasma too, is what I'm saying. (5.21.4, Kubuntu 21.04).

Comment: This makes the icons gigantic when using a wider vertical panel. It would be nice to have an option to simply set the size in pixels or similar.

Comment: It is possible to start plasma with `kstart5 plasmashell` after killing, see examples at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out p.s. nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

The setting to change icon sizes, located in Settings > Appearance > Icons > Advanced, seems to have been unusable for years.  I think this has been the case since some version of KDE 4.  Possibly it is related to whether the icon theme is in a resolution-independent format (svg).

A hidden `iconSize` setting was added around plasma-workspace 5.9.  Prior to the addition of this setting, qml files had to be edited.

To change the setting system-wide, edit the file:

```
/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/config/main.xml
```

This file will be overwritten whenever plasma-workspace is reinstalled or updated.

To change the setting for a specific user, edit:

```
$HOME/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

Look for the entry that corresponds to the system tray.  It will look something like this:

```
[Containments][#]
...
plugin=org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray
...
```

Then scroll down until you see something that looks like this:

```
[Containments][#][General]
extraItems=...
knownItems=...
showAllItems=true`
```

Then add:

```
iconSize=#
```

Where `#` is a number that refers to one of the following options:

```
0 ~ Small
1 ~ SmallMedium
2 ~ Medium
3 ~ Large
4 ~ Huge
5 ~ Enormous
```

To see the changes log off and on.  Or kill and restart `plasmashell` in a terminal window:

```
killall plasmashell ; sleep 1 ; kshell5 plasmashell
```

Comment: Sounds cool, but on my system (plasma-workspace 5.18.5) `iconSize=2` is too big, `0` is too small, `1` is same as `0`. Display is 14' and 4K, I've adjusted few settings to make it look ok and icon size is last one to fix :)

Comment: @DmitriyVinokurov Seems like a bug if 0 and 1 behave the same. I don't have any 4k displays, so may be related to that. I'm currently using 5.19.5.